# MongoDB: Request a field with "select: false" along with all standard fields

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Say we have a user schema:

```
name: String,
email: String,
mobile: { type: String, select: false }
```

`db.User.findOne({ email })` returns `name, email`

Say I want to also request `mobile`, I call `db.User.findOne({ email }, { mobile: 1 })`

However, this now *only* returns `mobile`. What if I want to request all of the standard fields, with the addition of some specific fields that have `select: false` by default?

It's not plausible to call `db.User.findOne({ email }, { name: 1, email: 1, mobile: 1 })` when actually I have dozens of such fields, and would have to make similar long calls throughout my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Mongo requires you to either accept all fields, or list out the ones you want, and AFAIK these are your only two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.select('+mobile')` it will change `{ projection: { mobile: 0 } }` to `{ projection: {  } }`

> +, it forces inclusion of the path, which is useful for paths excluded at the schema level.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select

> Specifies which document fields to include or exclude (also known as
> the query "projection")
>
> When using string syntax, prefixing a path with **- will flag that path
> as excluded**. When a path does not have the - prefix, it is included.
> Lastly, if a path is prefixed with **+, it forces inclusion of the path,
> which is useful for paths excluded at the schema level.**
>
> A projection must be either inclusive or exclusive. In other words,
> you must either list the fields to include (which excludes all
> others), or list the fields to exclude (which implies all other fields
> are included). The _id field is the only exception because MongoDB
> includes it by default.

```
db.User.findOne({ email }).select('+mobile')
```